# Using fxml with jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, javafx-2, fxml

I've seen how to write raw JavaFX code in Java, how to write FXML code in Java, how to write [raw JavaFX code in JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx), but can't seem to find anything on using FXML with JRuby. Is it currently possible to use FXML with JRuby? If so, are there any nice tutorials?

UPDATE: [JRubyFX 0.9.1 and later have FXML support](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use fxml with jruby.

I couldn't find any tutorials for this so I wrote my first Ruby program.  The program [demonstrates using fxml with jruby](https://gist.github.com/4266740).  It is a conversion of an earlier demonstration I wrote to [demonstrate using fxml with java](https://gist.github.com/3062859).

Output of the ruby version of the program:

[image: jrubyfxmlscreenshot]

Comment: Impressive given that is your first ruby program! I found JRubyFX also, and actually extended it so that the controller can be ruby also. See [JRubyFXML](https://github.com/byteit101/JRubyFXML)

Comment: Great work byte :-) Love how the #magic self-java-ifying become_java! allows injection of the fxml attributes into the ruby controller.